# I get undefined data from QSqlQueryModel in my ListView QML (SQLite database)

Tags: sqlite, qt, qml, qlistview, qsqlquerymodel

I am trying to display data that is in **two tables in the same database**. The tables in the database `plan_db.sqlite` were created using these queries:

`CREATE TABLE PlanOne (ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, Time VARCHAR(5), Name VARCHAR(50));`

`CREATE TABLE PlanTwo (ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, Time VARCHAR(5), Name VARCHAR(50));`

After inserting some data the structure of it looks like this:

```
PlanOne:
1|10:00|Event 1
2|14:00|Event 2
PlanTwo:
1|12:00|Event 3
2|16:00|Event 4
```

The connection is estabilished in the class `DatabaseHandler`:

```
QSqlDatabase plan_db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE", "plan_connection");
```

Then I have two `QSqlQueryModel`s that are supposed to represent the data from two tables: `PlanOne` and `PlanTwo`:

`MySqlModelOne`:

```
class MySqlModelOne : public QSqlQueryModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MySqlModelOne(QObject* parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    Q_INVOKABLE void refresh();
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const override;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const override;

private:
    QSqlDatabase plan_db = QSqlDatabase::database("plan_connection");
    QSqlQuery plan_qry;

    const static char* COLUMN_NAMES[];
    const static char* SQL_SELECT;
};


MySqlModelOne::MySqlModelOne(QObject* parent) : QSqlQueryModel(parent)
{
    if (plan_db.open()) qDebug("Plan database opened");
    else qDebug("Plan database not opened");

    plan_qry = QSqlQuery(plan_db);

    refresh();
}

void MySqlModelOne::refresh()
{
    plan_qry.exec(SQL_SELECT);
    this->setQuery(plan_qry);
}

QHash<int, QByteArray> MySqlModelOne::roleNames() const
{
    int idx = 0;
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames;
    while (COLUMN_NAMES[idx]) {
        roleNames[Qt::UserRole + idx + 1] = COLUMN_NAMES[idx];
        idx++;
    }
    return roleNames;
}

QVariant MySqlModelOne::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    QVariant value = QSqlQueryModel::data(index, role);
    if(role < Qt::UserRole)
    {
        value = QSqlQueryModel::data(index, role);
    }
    else
    {
        int columnIdx = role - Qt::UserRole - 1;
        QModelIndex modelIndex = this->index(index.row(), columnIdx);
        value = QSqlQueryModel::data(modelIndex, Qt::DisplayRole);
    }
    return value;
}

const char* MySqlModelOne::COLUMN_NAMES[] = { "ID", "Time", "Name", NULL};

const char* MySqlModelOne::SQL_SELECT = "SELECT * FROM PlanOne";
```

`MySqlModelTwo` is the copy of `MySqlModelOne` with appropriate changes like swapping every `One` with `Two` e.g:

```
const char* MySqlModelTwo::SQL_SELECT = "SELECT * FROM PlanTwo";
```

The classes are properly exposed to QML in `main.cpp`:

```
qmlRegisterType<MySqlModelOne>("com.sweak.mysqlmodelone", 1, 0, "MySqlModelOne");
qmlRegisterType<MySqlModelTwo>("com.sweak.mysqlmodeltwo", 1, 0, "MySqlModelTwo");
qmlRegisterType<DatabaseHandler>("com.sweak.databasehandler", 1, 0, "DatabaseHandler");
```

And finally the QML code that is supposed to display the data from `QSqlQueryModel`s using `ListView`s:

```
Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    DatabaseHandler {
        id: dataBaseHandler
    }

    MySqlModelOne {
        id: modelOne
    }

    MySqlModelTwo {
        id: modelTwo
    }

    ListView {
        id: listViewOne
        model: modelOne
        width: 100
        height: width
        anchors.left: parent.left
        delegate: RowLayout {
            Text {
                text: modelOne.Time
            }
            Text {
                text: modelOne.Name
            }
        }
    }

    ListView {
        id: listViewTwo
        model: modelTwo
        width: 100
        height: width
        anchors.left: listViewOne.right
        delegate: RowLayout {
            Text {
                text: modelTwo.Time
            }
            Text {
                text: modelTwo.Name
            }
        }
    }
```

After executing the program, the program window is blank (obviously) and I get the following error messages:

```
Plan database opened
Plan database opened
qrc:/main.qml:42:17: Unable to assign [undefined] to QString
qrc:/main.qml:45:17: Unable to assign [undefined] to QString
qrc:/main.qml:42:17: Unable to assign [undefined] to QString
qrc:/main.qml:45:17: Unable to assign [undefined] to QString
qrc:/main.qml:66:17: Unable to assign [undefined] to QString
qrc:/main.qml:69:17: Unable to assign [undefined] to QString
qrc:/main.qml:66:17: Unable to assign [undefined] to QString
qrc:/main.qml:69:17: Unable to assign [undefined] to QString
```

First two lines assure me that the database was properly opened in both `QSqlQueryModel`s but 8 lines that come next suggest to me that the data might not have been retrieved from both tables or it was retrieved but the format is `undefined` and obviously can't be assigned to `QString` and consequently can't be displayed via the `ListView`s. Can the problem be in the fact that I try to retrieve the data simultaneously from the same database through two different models? If so, how can I do this without causing such errors? Or maybe You have other ideas how to retrieve data from different tables in the same database using `QSqlQueryModel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the QML part of the program. After binding the `ModelOne` and `ModelTwo` to the property `model` of each of the `ListView`s while trying to get access to the fields in tables there was no need to to do this this way:

```
Text {
    text: modelOne.Time
}
```

instead it should have been:

```
Text {
    text: Time
}
```

Comment: Improvement: you can have your query as Q_PROPERTY in your sql model c++ class then declare two instances with different queries instead of creating two different c++ classes.