# qml uses C++ sqlquerymodel, when there is no data in the database table, qml shows that the property is not defined

Tags: qt, listview, qml, qsqlquerymodel

```
    Text {
        id: test1
        anchors.top: test.bottom
        anchors.topMargin: 5
        text: lat
        font.pixelSize: 14
   }
```

[image: Faulty behaviour]
qrc:/main.qml:70: ReferenceError: lat is not defined

when there is data in the database display is normal
[image: correct behaviour]

```
Timer{
        interval: 3000;
        running: true;
        repeat: true;
        onTriggered: {
            sqlModel.insertHistory(22.58369099635166, 113.94935604230989)
        }
    }

SqlQueryModel {
        id: sqlModel
        query: "select * from history order by rowid desc"
    }
```

Comment: How do you end up with the Text if no data is in the table? Aren't you using a Repeater with this Text as delegate? Please show a bit more code

Comment: my code like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66242814/i-get-undefined-data-from-qsqlquerymodel-in-my-listview-qml-sqlite-database    problem is the same.             

I use a timer to insert data

when i insert a data, I get undefined data

Comment: What I do now is to create a Listview after inserting the data, so it is no problem